# Facebook Login Button freezes after including firebase authentication

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an activity that logs into Facebook through Facebook Login Button.

It was working fine but since I added the firebase on it, the system freezes when I press the Facebook Login Button.

I added the Firebase authentication methods, and followed the steps needed according to Firebase website, but still I have this problem.

Logcat does not point any error, but the system freezes and craches due to a timeout exception.

There is some code that uses the class implementation [IdpCallback](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/ui/idp/AuthMethodPickerActivity.java). However, it it seems to be deprecated, as it is not into firebase package anymore.

The activity class I implemented is as follows.

```
public class ConfigurationActivity extends Activity {

    Button b_v_mm,b_som;
    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]


    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d("FireBase", "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("FireBase", "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w("FireBase", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            //Toast.makeText(FacebookLoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                             //       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    // [START on_start_check_user]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("FireBase", "onStart");
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        //updateUI(currentUser);
    }
    // [END on_start_check_user]

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - onActivityResult");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - onActivityResult");
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - After callbackManager");
/*
        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
            Log.d("AjudaFace", "AjudaFace - logout");
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }*/
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);

        //Botãp da barra de ferramentas que faz retornar para o Menu principal.
        b_v_mm = (Button) findViewById(com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja.R.id.b_v_mm);
        b_v_mm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ConfigurationActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        b_som = (Button) findViewById(com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja.R.id.b_som);
        //Altera opções de som.
        b_som.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {

                                          //Carrega opções de texto do botão, armazenadas no repositório de strings
                                          String s_som_on = getString(R.string.b_som_on);
                                          String s_som_off = getString(R.string.b_som_off);

                                          //Caso o som esteja desligado, o desliga.
                                          if(b_som.getText().equals(s_som_on)) {
                                              b_som.setText(s_som_off);
                                          }
                                          else //Caso o som esteja desligado, o liga.
                                              if (b_som.getText().equals(s_som_off)){
                                                  b_som.setText(s_som_on);
                                              }
                                      }
                                  }
        );

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


// ...
// Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email","public_profile");
        Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - Button Created");

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - Sucesso");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "LOGIN REALIZADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - Cancelado");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "LOGIN CANCELADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - Erro");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "LOGIN Erro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("LoginFace", exception.toString());
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Post the stack trace for the exception

Comment: I figured out that the problem is the required API level. I made another question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579107/facebook-login-requires-api-23-how-to-lower-the-api-level-requirement