# Facebook Login works only from API 24 - Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. error

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I added facebook login with firebase authentication on my application, but the login authentication works only from the Android API 24.

When I try to use a lower level API the screen freezes and the application stops working.

It is too high, most of the users have a lower [API level](https://www.statista.com/statistics/271774/share-of-android-platforms-on-mobile-devices-with-android-os/).

Indeed I intend to release the application for lower API levels.

The code I am using is bellow.

```
public class ConfigurationActivity extends Activity {

    Button b_v_mm,b_som;
    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]


    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d("FireBase", "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("FireBase", "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w("FireBase", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            //Toast.makeText(FacebookLoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                             //       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    // [START on_start_check_user]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("FireBase", "onStart");
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        //updateUI(currentUser);
    }
    // [END on_start_check_user]

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - onActivityResult");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - onActivityResult");
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - After callbackManager");
/*
        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
            Log.d("AjudaFace", "AjudaFace - logout");
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }*/
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);

        //Botãp da barra de ferramentas que faz retornar para o Menu principal.
        b_v_mm = (Button) findViewById(com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja.R.id.b_v_mm);
        b_v_mm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ConfigurationActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        b_som = (Button) findViewById(com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja.R.id.b_som);
        //Altera opções de som.
        b_som.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {

                                          //Carrega opções de texto do botão, armazenadas no repositório de strings
                                          String s_som_on = getString(R.string.b_som_on);
                                          String s_som_off = getString(R.string.b_som_off);

                                          //Caso o som esteja desligado, o desliga.
                                          if(b_som.getText().equals(s_som_on)) {
                                              b_som.setText(s_som_off);
                                          }
                                          else //Caso o som esteja desligado, o liga.
                                              if (b_som.getText().equals(s_som_off)){
                                                  b_som.setText(s_som_on);
                                              }
                                      }
                                  }
        );

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


// ...
// Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email","public_profile");
        Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - Button Created");


        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - Sucesso");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "LOGIN REALIZADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - Cancelado");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "LOGIN CANCELADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Log.d("LoginFace", "LoginFace - Erro");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "LOGIN Erro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("LoginFace", exception.toString());
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Objects used in MyApplication activity

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
```

**All objects used in the project are listed above

API 23 log:

> 12-02 17:22:26.900 2668-2745/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xaa9ba4e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xac3853a0)
>
> ```
>                                             [ 12-02 17:22:26.949  2668: 3361 D/         ]
>                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa19c5800, tid 3361
>
>
>                                             [ 12-02 17:22:26.950  2668: 3361 W/         ]
>                                             Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1
> ```
>
> ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1  12-02 17:22:26.977 2668-3361/? D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglCreateContext: 0xaa9ba900: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2 12-02 17:22:26.978
>   2668-3361/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa9ba900: ver 2 0
>   (tinfo 0xa23bf7e0) 12-02 17:22:26.980 2668-3361/? E/eglCodecCommon:
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf 12-02 17:22:26.980
>   2668-3361/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param
>   0x00008824 12-02 17:22:26.980 2668-3361/? E/eglCodecCommon:
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf 12-02 17:22:26.980
>   2668-3361/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param
>   0x00008824 12-02 17:22:27.135 2668-3361/? D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglCreateContext: 0xaa9ba9c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2 12-02 17:22:27.136
>   2668-3361/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa9ba9c0: ver 2 0
>   (tinfo 0xa23bf7e0) 12-02 17:22:29.740
>   2668-2668/com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja W/BindingManager: Cannot
>   call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2668
>   12-02 17:22:32.649 2668-2745/com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa9ba4e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo
>   0xac3853a0) 12-02 17:22:32.650
>   2668-2745/com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja E/Surface:
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40bdc00 12-02 17:22:32.676
>   2668-3361/com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa9ba900: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa23bf7e0) 12-02
>   17:22:32.687 2668-3361/com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa9ba9c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo
>   0xa23bf7e0) 12-02 17:22:32.704
>   2668-2745/com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa9ba4e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xac3853a0) 12-02
>   17:22:32.716 2668-2745/com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja
>   E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf 12-02
>   17:22:32.767 2668-3361/com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa9ba900: ver 2 0 (tinfo
>   0xa23bf7e0) 12-02 17:27:05.115
>   2668-2711/com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja W/DynamiteModule: Local
>   module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

This final one is probably the error cause:

12-02 17:27:05.115 2668-2711/com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

What can I do to lower the API level required?

Comment: My api level is 15 and its working like charm

Comment: Maybe a problem with your build dependencies or the version of Google Play services on your device.  Explain more about what is failing on devices with API less than 23.

Comment: How can I explore it? The application just freezes, it does not point any error on logcat.

Comment: I have posted the log... pehaps it someone can help using it.

Comment: After the log for `onStart()`, there are logs related to opening a Chromium web view: `WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider`.  Is there a WebView in your main layout? Also, your say the "app freezes".  Does that mean there is no response to screen touches and you have to reboot the device?

Comment: There is no response from the application. The device still working.

Comment: And there is no WebView... I do not know why it is being called... I will edit the questions with all objects used in the project.

Comment: ** Probably the facebook button calls the WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider ...

Comment: I have tested a bit more and now I have some exceptions...

Comment: The problem is probably the theme I am using >>
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
I tried to change to 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0', but I am getting some errors.

Comment: Nothing... changed the theme but the problem persists...

Comment: Are you testing on an Emulator? It is most likely to be failed since older emulator doesn't have Google Play Services. Try if you can update the emulator via SDK Manager. The best shot would be to try on a real device with recent Google Play Services version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resync your client with your Firebase app, and add again the .json file.

In android studio 2.3 just click on tools>firebase and in the assistant check if your app is connected to.

And also make sure that the package name is correct in both facebook developers account and firebase console.

[Use the latest Firebase library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Can you check your Google Play Services version?

The Android device should have Google Play services 9.0.0 or later

One of the reason for this problem could be, your Sign In Method inside Firebase > Auth Dashboard might be disabled